# pandas table subsets giving invalid type comparison error

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am using pandas and want to select subsets of data and apply it to other columns.
e.g.

- if there is data in column A; &
- if there is NO data in column B;
- then, apply the data in column A to column D

I have this working fine for now using `.isnull()` and `.notnull()`.
e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(4)),
                       'B' : pd.Series(np.nan),
                       'C' : pd.Series(['yes','yes','no','maybe'])})
df['D']=''

df
Out[44]: 
          A   B      C D
0  0.516752 NaN    yes  
1 -0.513194 NaN    yes  
2  0.861617 NaN     no  
3 -0.026287 NaN  maybe  

# Now try the first conditional expression
df['D'][df['A'].notnull() & df['B'].isnull()] \
=  df['A'][df['A'].notnull() & df['B'].isnull()]   
df
Out[46]: 
          A   B      C          D
0  0.516752 NaN    yes   0.516752
1 -0.513194 NaN    yes  -0.513194
2  0.861617 NaN     no   0.861617
3 -0.026287 NaN  maybe -0.0262874
```

When one adds a third condition, to also check whether data in column C matches a particular string, we get the error:

```
df['D'][df['A'].notnull() & df['B'].isnull() & df['C']=='yes'] \
=  df['A'][df['A'].notnull() & df['B'].isnull() & df['C']=='yes']   


  File "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 763, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 718, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

I have read that this occurs due to the different datatypes. And I can get it working if I change all the strings in column C for integers or booleans. We also know that string on its own would work, e.g. `df['A'][df['B']=='yes']` gives a boolean list.

So any ideas how/why this is not working when combining these datatypes in this conditional expression? What are the more pythonic ways to do what appears to be quite long-winded?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need add parentheses `()` to conditions, also better is use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) for selecting column with boolean mask which can be assigned to variable `mask`:

```
mask = (df['A'].notnull()) & (df['B'].isnull()) & (df['C']=='yes')
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

df.ix[mask, 'D'] = df.ix[mask, 'A']

print (df)
          A   B      C         D
0 -0.681771 NaN    yes -0.681771
1 -0.871787 NaN    yes -0.871787
2 -0.805301 NaN     no          
3  1.264103 NaN  maybe
```

Answer (score 10):

In case this solution doesn't work for anyone, another situation that happened to me was that even though I was reading all data in as `dtype=str` (and therefore doing any string comparison should be OK [ie `df[col] == "some string"`]), I had a column of all nulls, which becomes type `float`, which will give an error when comparing to a string.

To get around that, you can use `.astype(str)` to ensure a string to string comparison will be performed.